# Installing Python packages in command prompt not working well

Tags: python

First, I'm very new to Python, and am having trouble getting any installs to work properly in command prompt.  Here is the most recent example where, at the suggestion in the command prompt, I tried to upgrade to 'pip version 8.1.2', but got the messages indicated in the picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqYyv.png)

Answer (score 0):

As your Python is installed in Program Files (a protected directory), you'll need to run command prompt as an administrator.